# Best method to check if username already exist in forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I have the username entered from a form
Which method to use if that username is unique?

[`Membership.FindUsersByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk59azhc.aspx) or [`Membership.GetUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx)

Or any other methods?

I am asking this specifically because I didn't see a method returning bool as its common in checking unique values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Membership.GetUser` has slightly better performance. Also, `Membership.FindUsersByName` performes a LIKE statement if you are using SQL Membership, so it is not meant for unique names as you are trying to do.

Short answer: to get best performance and find unique names, use `Membership.GetUser`!

Answer (score -2):

```
There is a method in JQuery Form.validate you can use it for this pupose
```

here you can see the code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#formData").validate({
            rules: {
                fname: {
                    minLength: 3,
                    required: true,
                    remote: { url: "UserAccount/Register", type: post }
                },
            },
            messages : {
                minLength: "ATlesat 3 characters required for user name",
                required: "user name is required",
                remote : "User name already exist"
            } 
        });

    });
```